# Easily convert between Fabric JS IText and Textbox?

Tags: fabricjs

Is there a way to easily convert a Fabric JS IText into a TextBox (new in 1.6.0) and vice versa, without having to laboriously read and set every single property of them, i.e. some quick way of mapping between them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily do

```
var text = oldItext.text;
var textobj = oldItext.toObject();
delete textobj.text;
delete textobj.type;
var clonedtextobj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(textobj));

var textbox = new fabric.Textbox(text, clonedtextobj);
```

a note about use of json:

normal toObject method in Fabricjs does not take care of deep cloning. so the new textbox you create would share the same style object with the old itext. That is not necessarly bad untill you create 2 copies from 1.

if you are not using styles, a faster way is:

```
var text = oldItext.text;
    var textobj = oldItext.toObject();
    delete textobj.type;
    var textbox = new fabric.Textbox(text, textobj);
```

Comment: that's great thanks very much. To convert back from TextBox to IText using the top code (as I need styles and fonts) would I use the same code but swapping IText and TextBox references? E.g.

Comment: E.g. this code: `var text = oldTextBox.text;
var textobj = oldTextBox.toObject();
delete textobj.text;
delete textobj.type;
var clonedtextobj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(textobj));

var newitext = new fabric.IText(text, clonedtextobj); `

Comment: both itext and textbox use styles. yes u can use same code, just swap references